# Accessing last "number" of elements in String Array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, multithreading, asynchronous

I've got a String Array containing tens of thousands of elements and constantly growing, and am now looking for a way to obtain and process only last 3000 each 60 seconds in the background thread. 
I've looked into many different ways but am not certain with any of them.
Any input is welcome.

EDIT:
Thanks for your response guys.
Now what's the best way to run a background thread processing above while the intent camera is on?

Comment: do you mean String[] ? if so there's no real way to load "parts" of a primitive array - you'll need to change your datastructure to allow for "chunks"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] arr = {...};

for(int i = arr.length-3000; i < arr.length ; i++){
     arr[i];  //Do something.
}
```